# Reciprocal of conditional Binomial -provide upper bound

Tags: probability

Let $X\sim binom(N,p)$.
How can I compute a close upper bound for

$$E(\frac{1}{X}|X\geq 1)$$?

I know that $$E(\frac{1}{X+1})=\frac{1-(1-p)^{n+1}}{p(n+1)},$$
but I don't know how to show an upper bound for the above equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Say the desired quantity is $f(N,p)$ and the known quantity is $g(N,p)$. You have

$$f(N,p) = \frac{\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n} P(X=n)}{1-P(X=0)}.$$

$$g(N,p) = \sum_{n=0}^N \frac{1}{n+1} P(X=n) = P(X=0) + \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n+1} P(X=n).$$

Therefore

$$(1-(1-p)^N)f(N,p)-g(N,p) = -(1-p)^N + \sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n(n+1)} P(X=n).$$

If you're interested in large $N$, since the mapping is a decreasing function, a decent way to get an upper bound for the sum is to use a lower tail bound for the binomial distribution. You have

\begin{align}
\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{1}{n(n+1)} P(X=n) & = \sum_{n=1}^c \frac{1}{n(n+1)} P(X=n) + \sum_{n=c+1}^N \frac{1}{n(n+1)} P(X=n) \\
& \leq \frac{1}{2} P(X \leq c) + \frac{1}{(c+1)(c+2)} P(X \geq c+1) \\
& = \frac{1}{2} P \left ( X \leq Np \left ( 1-\frac{Np-c}{Np} \right ) \right ) + \frac{1}{(c+1)(c+2)} \\
& \leq \frac{1}{2} e^{-\frac{(Np-c)^2}{2Np}} + \frac{1}{(c+1)(c+2)}
\end{align}

by the Chernoff bound. A decent guess for a good value of $c$ would be something like $Np-a\sqrt{Np}$ where $a$ is big enough that $e^{-a^2/2}$ will be small, but still much smaller than $\sqrt{Np}$.

Comment: tTere is a mistake in the answer (should be (1-p)^N and not 1/(N+1)*p^n) but I accepted the answer

Comment: @lan it is already in the second term.
you should take $X=0$ in the first term (not $X=N$)

Comment: @user3563894 Oh, you're right, that's an artifact of a different version where I was comparing the two with the denominators the same and the values of $X$ different, which I found more difficult to work with later on. I'll fix it.